# Is the ribbon cable that connects screen and keyboard in a laptop changeable?

Tags: laptop, keyboard, display, cable

I'm not sure if the word changeable even exsists, but it summarizes my question pretty well. I want to know if the ribbon cable connecting the keyboard to the displayer can be replaced.

Comment: Anything is possible, but generally they are not user serviceable parts.

Comment: Please edit your question to add more details liveth exact make and model of the laptop in question. It all depends on the make and model of laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, although it is not generally recommended to attempt this type of replacement.

- **It may be difficult to find the right part.** Although there are
  standards (e.g. eDP, LVDS) that may apply, typically these cables are
  manufactured to a specific length and with built-in bend radii for
  the particular laptop chassis and component configuration. Too short and cable won't reach. Too
  long and the excess cable may not fit into the chassis.
- **It is delicate work, often with little or no documentation to follow.** Laptop manufacturers typically only intend for their own or similarly qualified and experienced personnel to work on most internal laptop components. Although changing RAM or a disk drive may be fairly straightforward, the rest of a laptop design generally optimizes for size over user-serviceability. As such, the connectors and wiring may be hard to get to, easy to break, and hard to disconnect and reconnect properly for the unexperienced.

If possible, seek a qualified service center that can take responsibility for the replacement.